# Implementing a "Did you mean?" feature as used on Amazon and Google

Tags: php, search

I have a website and I am using Google search widget on it. Now I would like to have, if possible, the feature "Do you mean:" as used on [Amazon](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias=aps&field-keywords=claret%20paint&x=0&y=0) and [Google](http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy&hl=en&source=hp&q=asyncronous). This feature would allow a user to search for a product and if the desired product does not exist then the search results will offer a suggestion. E.g. if a visitor is looking for a "[Wonder Mop 3000](http://i236.photobucket.com/albums/ff199/Seronelle/shaggydogREUT_468x497.jpg)", but the site is offering only "[Wonder Mop 1000](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_No1_P3LAXvM/TQylH2J1K_I/AAAAAAAAAE4/tSIOHJQ8i2w/s1600/cat-cleaning.jpg)" then above the search results, the result will look like:

```
Did you mean: "Wonder Mop 1000"
---------------------------------------
Results for "Wonder Mop 3000"
...
```

Is this possible with google search or I will need a different search engine?

Comment: I find it peculiar that someone would associate the "did you mean" feature with Amazon rather than Google...

Comment: Regarding "I am using Google search on it", do you mean you're using the Google search widget within your page? Or are you detecting the search query from Google and displaying filtered results? Or something else?

Comment: @NullUserException - Agreed. Edited question to include Google search as well.

Comment: @RobB Thanks. @ somethingkindawierd Yes I am using Google search widget

Comment: Are you using it purely for products? If so, how many products do you have in the system?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is an excellent, accessible article by Peter Norvig, Director of Research at Google on how to implement the "did you mean" feature in a few lines of code. It's really a great read.

http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html

Essentially you will need a 'corpus' or list of valid searches, and given a search, you will try to come up with the 'most likely' correct search. At the bottom there are links to implementations in various languages including PHP, of course. Check it out :)

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link! It is certainly a great, somewhat mind-bending read :)